# How to do multiline shell script in Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

right now I am using a shell script in ansible that would be much more readable if it was on multiple lines

```
- name: iterate user groups
  shell: groupmod -o -g {{ item['guid'] }} {{ item['username'] }} ....more stuff to do
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Just not sure how to allow multiline script in Ansible shell module

Comment: Also consider using the ansible 'script' command and use an external file

Answer (score 417, accepted):

Ansible uses YAML syntax in its playbooks.  YAML has a number of block operators:

- The `>` is a folding block operator.  That is, it joins multiple lines together by spaces.  The following syntax:

  ```
  key: >
    This text
    has multiple
    lines
  ```

  Would assign the value `This text has multiple lines\n` to `key`.
- The `|` character is a literal block operator.  This is probably what you want for multi-line shell scripts. The following syntax:

  ```
  key: |
    This text
    has multiple
    lines
  ```

  Would assign the value `This text\nhas multiple\nlines\n` to `key`.

You can use this for multiline shell scripts like this:

```
- name: iterate user groups
  shell: |
    groupmod -o -g {{ item['guid'] }} {{ item['username'] }} 
    do_some_stuff_here
    and_some_other_stuff
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

There is one caveat: Ansible does some janky manipulation of arguments to the `shell` command, so while the above will generally work as expected, the following won't:

```
- shell: |
    cat <<EOF
    This is a test.
    EOF
```

Ansible will actually render that text with leading spaces, which means the  shell will never find the string `EOF` at the beginning of a line.  You can avoid Ansible's unhelpful heuristics by using the `cmd` parameter like this:

```
- shell:
    cmd: |
      cat <<EOF
      This is a test.
      EOF
```

Comment: What if using `ansible` instead of `ansiable-playbook`?

Comment: Using `shell: >` actually results in ansible inserting line breaks, so this is incorrect.

Comment: Nowhere in this answer do I show an example of using `shell: >`, and furthermore your statement is simply incorrect: Ansible doesn't know whether you use `"` or `>` or `|`; it only knows what text it receives after parsing the YAML. The `>` quote operating is a folding operator and does not preserve newlines. If you're seeing different behavior, feel free to open a question and I would be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: There's a slight gotcha about the indentation of the rows beneath `>`: they all must be indented the same amount for the folding to work correctly (at least in Ansible). I posted a complementary answer about this. This might be what @PhilippLudwig was seeing?

Answer (score 26):

Tried with ansible 2.0.0.2:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: multiline shell command
      shell: >
        ls --color
        /home
      register: stdout

    - name: debug output
      debug: msg={{ stdout }}
```

The shell command is collapsed into a single line, as in `ls --color /home`

Reference (visited in 2021):
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html ==> search form "multiple lines" in the page.

Comment: Yeah but in the shell `>` has a very specific meaning. I tried this and it did not work as expected.

Comment: That is why it's just in the first line, not in the subsequent ones. It worked fine for me with ansible 2.0 as I wrote, although it didn't print out the full ls output with ansible 1.9.4. What version of Ansible did you use?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani It does not work with ansible 2.10.8.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a space before the EOF delimiter allows to avoid cmd:

```
- shell: |
    cat <<' EOF'
    This is a test.
    EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this syntax as it allows to set configuration parameters for the shell:

```yaml
---
- name: an example
  shell:
    cmd: |
      docker build -t current_dir .
      echo "Hello World"
      date

    chdir: /home/vagrant/
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick caveat about the folding `>` operator that had me scratching my head for a while: the rows indented beneath it have to be at the same indentation level for the folding to happen correctly, at least when using Ansible.

I was converting an existing multi-line shell command that had `\` line endings to escape newlines and had indented every row below the first one two spaces more. I used `shell: >`, removed the backslashes and preserved the existing indentation.

The newlines were preserved, and I was losing my mind, because everywhere it said that `>` should convert them to spaces.

See below for an example:

```yaml
# Converts into ls -la /tmp, as expected
- name: working shell command that folds newlines
  shell: >
    ls
    -la
    /tmp

# Tries to run -la and /tmp as their own commands
- name: failing shell command that does not fold newlines
  shell: >
    ls
      -la
      /tmp
```

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lineinfile collection  to append the file, attribute create to create file if not exist and multi line string using "|".

```
- name: Add a line to a file if the file does not exist
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: ~/.ssh/config
    line: |
      Host {{item.COMPONENT}} {{item.COMPONENT}}.{{ZONE}}
        HostName {{r53_var_one.resource_record_sets[0].resource_records[0].value}}
        User centos
        Port 22
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
    create: yes
    mode: '0600'
```

Answer (score 1):

To know how to multilines works in ansbile, you may want to test this playbook to actually know what pipe (LF->LF) and Greather than (LF->space) are about.

```
- hosts: all,localhost
  tasks:
   - name: greather_than
     debug:
      msg: >
        a
        b
        c
   - name: pipe
     debug:
      msg: |
        a
        b
        c
```

This is tested this way.

```
# ansible-playbook test.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [all,localhost] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [greater_than] ****************************************************************************  
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "a  b c\n"
}

TASK [pipe] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "a \nb\nc\n"
}

 PLAY RECAP  ***********************************************************************************
 localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0       skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

#
```