# Hold multiple packages using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to hold multiple packages using ansible-playbook but it doesn't work with me.

Using the below code it holds the first package then un-hold it then hold the second package

Here is my code

```
- name: Prevent packages from being upgraded
  dpkg_selections:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    selection: hold
  with_items:
    - postgresql
    - docker
```

Here is the output from the server side while the code executing
[image]
the first line before executing
the second line is the output when the first package was hold
the third line when the second package was held and it is stoped

I don't understand why the behavior is like that?
and how can I hold multiple packages at a time using ansible?

NOTE: I already followed the instruction from Anible doc https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dpkg_selections_module.html
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
- name: Prevent packages from being upgraded
  dpkg_selections:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    selection: hold
  loop:
    - postgresql
    - docker
```

In my case, the output from the server side after the execution was the full list of packages.

Comment: According the documentation of Ansible [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop), the here provided and accepted solution is similar or identic to the in the question raised non working example. Is there some more information available, except the "_works for me_"?

Answer (score 2):

Already for performance and resource reasons, providing the packages as list might be better.

```
- name: Prevent packages from being upgraded
  dpkg_selections:
    name: ['postgresql', 'docker']
    selection: hold
```

However, your test reported

```
dpkg: error: unexpected data after package and selection
```

Therefore it might be that the module can't handle lists, so I had a look into [the source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=dpkg_selections) [`dpkg_selections.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c5d8dc0e119c8a1632afae8b55fb15e2a4a44177/lib/ansible/modules/dpkg_selections.py). It seems to be a somehow simple wrapper

```
module.run_command([dpkg, '--set-selections'], data="%s %s" % (name, selection), check_rc=True)
```

which just provide information for one module. I also assume the module should work `with_items`, but it seems to be not the case because of your question.

According man pages, the command `dpkg` itself seems to be able to handle a package list, but provided as character separated value file

```
dpkg --set-selections < /tmp/pkg_list
```

with delimiter   in the format

```
postgresql hold
docker hold
```

A simple workaround could help in your case.

```
- name: Prevent packages from being upgraded
  shell:
    cmd: |
      dpkg --set-selections << EOF
      postgresql hold
      docker hold
      EOF
    warn: false
    register: result
```

You may need to implement some error and status handling by yourself, i.e.

```
changed_when: result.rc ...
failed_when: result.rc ...
```

**Thanks to**

- [How to do multiline shell script in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230184/)

Comment: no syntax error  ` “msg”: “dpkg: error: unexpected data after package and selection at line 1",
    “rc”: 2,
    “stderr”: “dpkg: error: unexpected data after package and selection at line 1\n”,
    “stderr_lines”: [
        “dpkg: error: unexpected data after package and selection at line 1”
    ],
    “stdout”: “”,
    “stdout_lines”: [] `

Comment: @Sara, thanks for providing test results, I've updated the answer accordingly.