# How to run multiline shell script in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have encountered an error while running this, I have checked the indentation but not sure why

```
- name: Ensure System accounts are non-login
    shell: >
             egrep -v '^\+' /etc/passwd |
             awk -F: '($1!="root" && $1!="sync" && $1!="shutdown" && $1!="halt" && $3<1000 && $7!="/usr/sbin/nologin" && $7!="/bin/false") {print}' 
    register: system

- debug:
    msg: "{{ system.stdout }}"
```

This is the error, I don't understand it.

```
The offending line appears to be:

    - name: Ensure System accounts are non-login
        shell: >
             ^ here
```

Comment: From your question I wonder if you are trying to (re)implement what might be public available already. If you are interested in Ansible examples for Linux CIS you might take advantage from in example [Ansible RHEL-7 CIS Benchmark](https://github.com/HarryHarcourt/Ansible-RHEL7-CIS-Benchmarks/) or [RHEL-8 CIS](https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/RHEL8-CIS) or [Ansible Galaxy CIS Security](https://galaxy.ansible.com/dsglaser/cis_security).

Comment: If you are interested in [How to do multiline shell script in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230184/) you'll find the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230416/6771046).

Comment: If you like to pipe together `egrep -v '^\+' /etc/passwd | awk ...` you may just use it one line like `cmd: egrep -v '^\+' /etc/passwd | awk ...`.

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems that it is about:

```
- name: Ensure System accounts are non-login
  shell: >
```

instead of

```
- name: Ensure System accounts are non-login
    shell: >
```

Comment: It is not only about the indention, but also the incorrect `>` versus correct `|`.