# How to emulate raw command with EOF?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to emulate this behavior with Ansible [`raw`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html) command but I could not find any feature that achieve this

```bash
ssh user@host.com <<EOF
   command
   exit
EOF
```

Comment: So it is just about [How to do multiline shell script in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230416/6771046).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply sending the script:

```
command
exit
```

To the remote host. The `<<EOF` and `EOF` parts are parsed by your local shell and aren't part of the command. The equivalent ansible task would be:

```
- raw: |
    command
    exit
```

In most cases (if the remote target is running a semi-standard shell), you won't need the `exit` either; the script will exit after the last command completes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send a multiline commands via ssh, perhaps you have connected with ssh already with ansible when you set **ansible_connection** variable, e.g. in your inventory file:

```ini
[my_host_group]
host.com

[my_host_group:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_ssh_user=user
```

Then execute a tasks with bash:

```yaml
- name: Executing multiline command on host.com under user
  ansible.builtin.shell: command
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['my_host_group'][0] }}"
  become: False
```

Or just use **ansible.builtin.command** module instead of ansible.builtin.shell if your command is simple and not multi line.

You don't need an `exit` at the end of your script either (until you want to change an exit code and return them to ansible). 'Failed when' conditions is your firend:

```yaml
- name: Executing multiline command on host.com under user
  ansible.builtin.shell: command
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['my_host_group'][0] }}"
  register: your_script_results
  ignore_errors: True
  become: False

- name: Print an exit code on script error
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Script was failed with {{ your_script_results.rc }} exit code"
  when: your_script_results.failed
```