# && operator creates a new connection in Ansible

Tags: ansible, db2

I am new to ansible and I want to run a shell command for db2 which connects to db2 and run the **.sql** file for me, However it creates a new connection after **&&** operator and for **.sql** command it then say no connection found. How can I use **&&** and still run the playbook successfully?

Here is the task I am trying to run :

```
- name: Update file
  shell: "db2 connect to db2_db user db2_user using db2_password && db2 -tvf file.sql"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ work_dir }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ user }}"
  become_flags: -i
```

The error I am getting is:

```
The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a \nvalid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:\n  A database connection does not exist.
```

Comment: Except from the fact that the approach isn't recommended and one should use dedicated Ansible Modules for the task(s), does this answer your question? [How to do multiline shell script in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230184/how-to-do-multiline-shell-script-in-ansible)

Comment: @U880D no it does not, I am looking for the solution on how to use && and still avoid the errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching to see if anyone else ran into our problem with `&&`, and our solution was to use `;` in its place. `&&` worked fine in RHEL 7, but the server was upgraded to RHEL 8 over the weekend and the task file started failing.

So try replacing `&&` with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your default shell may not handle `&&` correctly. Try use:

```
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

in the shell module it might help. But if I were you, I would use multiline shell what solve the problem for sure:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Test touch
    shell: |
      touch a
      touch b
```

Comment: but I am using for bash only, and is there a way for me to use && and still run in the same connection?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What I wrote first, still not working? If not, the second part exactly do the same as `&&` and I don't see why it isn't good enough.