# How to execute a set of commands though the vmware_vm_shelll module in ansible?

Tags: ansible, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I wanted to  unjoin  a windows machine  from a specific domain and join the machine to a WORKGROUP with the help of the domain credentials. I used  Powershell credential objects to prevent the hassle of  authentication prompts in the automation . The first command executed successfully ($Pass = {{ ansible_password }} | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ) . The 3 PS commands are as follows;

```
$Pass = {{ ansible_password }} | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('{ ansible_user }', $Pass)
Remove-Computer -UnJoinDomainCredential $credential -WorkgroupName 'LOCAL' -PassThru -Verbose -Force -Restart
```

.

```
- name: join  {{ vm_cloned_name }} to workgroup with manual reboot in later task
       community.vmware.vmware_vm_shell:
         datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
         folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/vm/"
         vm_id: "{{ vm_cloned_name }}"
         vm_username: "{{ localusername }}"
         vm_password: "{{ password }}"
         vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
         vm_shell_args: "{{ $Pass = '{{ ansible_password }}' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ; $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('{{ ansible_user }}', $Pass) ;  Remove-Computer -UnJoinDomainCredential $credential -WorkgroupName 'LOCAL' -PassThru -Verbose -Force -Restart }}"
         vm_shell_cwd: 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop'
         wait_for_process: true
         timeout: 100
       register: workgroup_res
       tags: join-workgroup
```

the ansible error logs are as follows:

```
cmd_line": "\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('abc@dc.e', $Pass)",
  "changed": false,
  "msg": "Failed to execute command",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do multiline shell script in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230184/how-to-do-multiline-shell-script-in-ansible)

Comment: No the built in shell module in ansible only used for linux hosts in this case  the host is a windows host

Comment: That question is not about Linux/Windows difference, it is about Multiline YAML strings syntax that could fix your issue. If changing your command to multiline doesn't help, then the reason is likely related to your VM, not to Ansible.

Comment: I've noticed an issue with templating itself so posted an answer. But my comment on multiline strings still applies.

Comment: Just curious why you are using the vmware module vs WinShell?

Comment: Ah that is because the requirement is to run  a script in a remote windows vm without a WinRM connection . Windows ansible modules requires  an established  WinRM connection .  The vmware module can run a script even without a WinRM connection

Comment: That's because the VMware module connects to the VMware API, not to the machine directly. But doesn't VMware itself use WinRM?

Comment: The issue is we want to execute the script after the removal of a network adapter . In that case can we assume winrm connection still persists between the hosts.

Comment: I'd assume that we can't, but I'm not proficient in Windows administration. Once again, I think this is a separate question, it does not relate to Ansible anymore, and probably belongs to another StackExchange site.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Jinja2 templating incorrectly:

- you have everything within the first set of curly braces, including PoweShell commands
- within that, you have ansible variables within another set of curly braces
- on top of that, these internal curly braces are quoted.
  It should not work like that.

A correct templating would look like this (note I use multiline YAML strings to improve readability):

```yaml
     - name: Join {{ vm_cloned_name }} to workgroup with manual reboot in later task
       community.vmware.vmware_vm_shell:
         datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
         folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/vm/"
         vm_id: "{{ vm_cloned_name }}"
         vm_username: "{{ localusername }}"
         vm_password: "{{ password }}"
         vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
         vm_shell_args: |
           $Pass = '{{ ansible_password }}' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ;
           $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('{{ ansible_user }}', $Pass) ;
           Remove-Computer -UnJoinDomainCredential $credential -WorkgroupName 'LOCAL' -PassThru -Verbose -Force -Restart
         vm_shell_cwd: 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop'
         wait_for_process: true
         timeout: 100
       register: workgroup_res
       tags: join-workgroup
```

Without multiline YAML it would be the same - you would need to remove the curly braces surrounding the whole command.

Comment: I tried . But still gives an error   "msg": "A general system error occurred: vix error codes = (1, 0).\n",

Comment: I believe it's worth to edit your question then or ask it on ServerFault because, as I said previously, this error is not related to Ansible.

Comment: Is there a way to create a powershell script  and save it in the remote windows VM via an ansible module?

Comment: Sure, but as far as I know, any module would require a WinRM connection that you don't want to use.