# How set up VNet integration and Access Restriction for Azure WebApp from ansible

Tags: linux, azure, ansible, azure-web-app-service

Pls help !
I need create some web app from ansible, and add this web app to an existing VNet.

For create WebApp i use ansible module - `azure_rm_webapp`, and all work fine but i can`t find any way configuring network for created web app.

Can i do it from ansible?
How can i do this ?
I read about ansible module for creating network (may be there i can add , but also not find )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that we can not do VNet integration using ansible module. Here are [all modules for Azure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules#azure) by using ansible and ansible-playbooks [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks).

In this case, you may consider using some [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module), [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html#script-module), or [win_shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_shell_module.html#win-shell-module) modules to execute some commands on target hosts after the VM provision. Here is an [arm template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-app-service-regional-vnet-integration/) for deploying a web app with VNet integration.

If you consider other automatic deployment tools. I would like to recommend the [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) tool. it supports resource [azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection.html) which makes you manage an App Service Virtual Network Association. Also, you can use `ip_restriction` block and `scm_ip_restriction` block under the resource [azurerm_app_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html) to configure Access restriction.

Comment: Big thanks for answer !
I`m new in WebApp so , how can i run shell script from ansible ? I need use shell module , and this command will run on "host" machine in azure ?
or i need install azure cli on my  host where i run ansible and run azure cli command ?

Comment: I think you need to install azure cli on the host and copy the script to the remote host then run the shell module to execute the commands. [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160776/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-server-using-ansible), [eg2](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-shell-examples/)