# How to escape double quotes inside single quotes in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to render `"` as is in my Ansible code below.

I am trying to escape the output of `cachedNodeModulesPath` with `\"` expecting that the resulting command is like this `mv "/src/somepath/nodemodules" || restofcommand`.

What I get instead is `mv \"restofcommand` and my script fails during execution.

My Ansible code is:

```yaml
- name: "yarn install {{ codePath }}"
  shell: "docker container run --rm --entrypoint='' -u root \
              -v {{ codePath }}:/usr/src/app \
              -w /usr/src/app \
              node:16.4.0 /bin/bash -c 'mv \"{{ cachedNodeModulesPath }}\" node_modules || YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache yarn install'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am trying to escape the output of `cachedNodeModulesPath` with `\"`*

According [Manipulating strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) you could probably use

```yaml
{{ cachedNodeModulesPath | quote }}
```

> *To add quotes for shell usage*

Furthermore, there are other notations possible in YAML. In example by using `|`, literal block operator like

```yaml
  - name: Exec sh script
    shell:
      cmd: |
        docker container run --rm --entrypoint='' -u root \
               -v {{ codePath }}:/usr/src/app \
               -w /usr/src/app \
               node:16.4.0 /bin/bash -c 'mv {{ cachedNodeModulesPath | quote }} node_modules || YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache yarn install'
    register: result
```

*... only partially tested because of lack of environment*

At least, for a key value of

```yaml
    cachedNodeModulesPath: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test"
```

it will try to execute

```bash
/bin/bash -c 'mv /home/user/test node_modules || YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache yarn install'
```

---

If double quotes are needed and not single quotes

```yaml
  vars:

    codePath: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
    cachedNodeModulesPath: "/home/domain user/test"

  tasks:

  - name: Exec sh script
    shell:
      cmd: |
        docker container run --rm --entrypoint='' -u root \
               -v {{ codePath }}:/usr/src/app \
               -w /usr/src/app \
               node:16.4.0 /bin/bash -c 'mv "{{ cachedNodeModulesPath }}" node_modules || YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache yarn install'
    register: result
```

will try to execute

```bash
/bin/bash -c 'mv "/home/domain user/test" node_modules || YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache yarn install'
```

---

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to execute a shell script on a remote server using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594837/6771046)
- [How to do multiline shell script in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230416/6771046)

Comment: In this case, I would prefer using the `>-` operator. Since then, no newlines are parsed.